# SiteNavigationElement Schema using JSON Format

Tags: seo, schema

I have added the below Schema JSON code for SiteNavigationElemen on the  section but this one is not fetching on https://search.google.com/test/rich-results. I want to show on Google search result. Could you please guide me this one code is correct or not.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@graph": 
    [
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#table-of-contents",
          "name": "EX",
          "url": "https://example1.com"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#table-of-contents",
          "name": "EX",
          "url": "https://example1.com"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#table-of-contents",
          "name": "EX",
          "url": "https://example1.com"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#pagination",
          "name": "EX",
          "url": "https://example1.com"
      },
      {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
          "@id":"#pagination",
          "name": "EX",
          "url": "https://example1.com"
      }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heena, it is because https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/video
There are only specific schemas that show up in rich results, but more work. They just won't work with that testing tool. I recommend https://validator.schema.org/